# notify() and notifyAll() doesn't work in my java code

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, notify

So I have been working on a simple wait/notify example in Java and for some reason I have not been able to get it to run properly. If anyone is able to see what might be the issue It would be very appreciated!

```
class producer implements Runnable {
    StringBuffer sb;
    producer() {
        sb=new StringBuffer("");
    }

    public void run () {
        synchronized(sb) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try { 
                    sb.append(i+" ");
                    System.out.println("Appending ... "); 
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
            sb.notify(); 
        }
    }
}

class consumer implements Runnable {
    producer p;
    consumer(producer pp) {
        this.p = pp;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Rreached");
        synchronized(p.sb) { 
            try { 
                 p.sb.wait(); 
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            System.out.println(p.sb);
        }
    }
}

class Thread_Comunication {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        producer p = new producer();
        consumer c = new consumer(p);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(p);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(c);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Appending ...
Rreached   // randome Position
Appending ...
Appending ...
Appending ...
Appending ...
Appending ...
Appending ...
Appending ...
Appending ...
Appending ...
```

So for some reason the thread `t1` does not wake up the `t2` or am I missing something else entirely?

Comment: At least put `e.printStackTrace();` in your `catch` blocks otherwise you'll never know if an exception occurred.

Comment: Note: Java language conventions are that class names start with a capital name (thus, `producer` is not a good class name). No underscores are used in class, method or package names, only in names of constants which are all-capital. Classes have names like `ThreadCommunication`, not `Tread_Comunication`. It is also recommended to give variables meaningful names, not 'p' and 'pp'.

Comment: Close voter: the posted code does reproduce the problem (at least as much as it can, since the code depends on a race condition that may or may not occur at the scheduler's discretion). Between the posted code and the output shown it is practical to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html -- read it!

Answer (score 3):

Notify doesn't do anything unless another thread is waiting. Your code depends solely on notifying, for it to work the consumer has to run before the producer.

According to your output it happens that the producer runs first; it will execute in its entirety before the consumer gets a chance to run. (For the consumer to run it needs to acquire the lock on sb, which the producer is holding onto.) The producer calls notify but no thread is waiting so it has no effect. Then the consumer waits and no notification comes, so it hangs indefinitely.

If the consumer runs first then the code will terminate normally.

Avoid writing code that depends on one thread happening to run before another, because you don't have control of what executes first. When you wait you need to do it inside of a loop that tests a condition. One of multiple reasons for this is that if the condition is set before the thread starts to wait, the thread can know not to wait.

Changing the code to use a condition:

```
import java.io.*;

class producer implements Runnable {
    StringBuffer sb;
    boolean done = false;
    producer() {
        sb=new StringBuffer("");
    }

    public void run () {

        synchronized(sb) {

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                try { 
                    sb.append(i+" ");
                    System.out.println("Appending ... "); 
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
            sb.notify(); 
            done = true;
        }


    }
}

class consumer implements Runnable {
    producer p;
    consumer(producer pp) {
        this.p=pp;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Rreached");
        synchronized(p.sb) { 
            try { 
                while (!p.done) {
                 p.sb.wait(); 
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}

            System.out.println(p.sb);
        }
    }
}


public class Communication {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
        producer p= new producer();
        consumer c= new consumer(p);

        Thread t1= new Thread(p);
        Thread t2= new Thread(c);
        t2.start();
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> So I have been working on a simple wait/notify example in Java and for some reason I have not been able to get it to run properly.

The problem with your code is that the `notify()` is not persisted.  If the `producer` enters the `synchronized` block *first* then the `consumer` will not be able to enter it and get to the `wait` until the `producer` exits the loop and finishes.  Since all of the `notify` calls happen *inside* of the `synchronized` block, by the time the `consumer` gets to the `wait()`, the `producer` has finished and is no longer calling `notify`.  This means that the `consumer` is hung.

Even if you start the `consumer` first, you still have a race condition that might cause the `producer` to get into its `synchronized` block first -- this is especially true because the `consumer` calls a `System.out.println()` which takes time.  Although not a "fix", if you slow down the `producer` with a `Thread.sleep(100)` before the `synchronized` call, you should see that it now works because the `consumer` gets to its `wait()` *before* the `producer` locks it out.

There are a couple of ways for you to properly fix this.  Typically we use wait/notify *and* another variable which the `consumer` should check.  In your case this could be the `sb` variable itself since it is protected.  So the `consumer` could do something like:

```
synchronized (p.sb) { 
    try {
        // do we need to wait to see if the producer added stuff?
        if (p.sb.length() == 0) {
            p.sb.wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // this is always a good pattern to preserve the interrupt flag
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return;
    }
}
```